# Persistent html menu in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a menu that is shown on top of the web page when you click the extension button. I would like the menu to remain on page reload and when you navigate the domain - is this possible?

**mainifest.json**

```
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": true
 },
  "content_scripts": [
   {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
  "css": ["grid.css"],
  "js": ["jquery-2.0.0.min.js"],
       "all_frames": true
   }
 ],
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "grid.js" });
});
```

**grid.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").append("<ul id='menu'><li><a id='add' href='#'>Add div</a></li></ul>")
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to use `LocalStorage` to save information in the same moment you click the browser action of your extension.

Then in your content_script, you can check for that information in the LocalStorage and show the menu without having to press the extension button.

Briefly, what I mean is:

**manifest.js**

```
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": true
 },
  "content_scripts": [
   {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
  "css": ["grid.css"],
  "js": ["jquery-2.0.0.min.js", "content.js"],
       "all_frames": true
   }
 ],
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "grid.js" });
   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {menu:'show'}, function(response) {
    console.log('Persistent menu started');
});
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.menu === "show")
    {
        localStorage.setItem("show_menu", "Yes");
    }
  });

var showMenu = localStorage.getItem("show_menu");

if(showMenu === "Yes")
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").append("<ul id='menu'><li><a id='add' href='#'>Add div</a></li></ul>")
    });
}
```

Comment: The browser action's `localStorage` is tied to the extension, the content script's `localStorage` belongs to the page. This suggestion won't work.

Comment: Chrome's API makes possible to send information to and from the extension scripts and content_script, why won't it work?

Comment: That was not clear from your answer. If you remove this ambiguity by improving the answer, I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Would MythThrazz's solution result in the following the behaviour:

1. Once the user clicks the extension button the persistent menu would be added to the current tab.
2. If the user selects another tab and reloads this tab the persistent menu would also appear on this tab.

If this is so, instead of using "show_menu" as the key, one could use the url as the key. That would allow the user to initiate the persistent menu per url.

Comment: thanks for this, but it seems to be working on a per tab basis as is.

Comment: The per tab basis will work only for cases where the domain of the sites loaded in the other tabs are different from the one where the click was done. One would expect in a test where the second tab has a url from the same domain as the first tab (with a different url though) that the menu will get added on page load. Perhaps this is what you may want in some situations. However, it is worth noting that localStorage entries created from content scripts are domain scoped (full domain).

Comment: Sorry you are 100%, correct. Do you know how to limit the extension to the scope of the current tab?

Comment: Did you try using the url of the current page as the key instead of the "show_menu" key value? That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "permenu",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "19icon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "permenu"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["extension.js", "jquery-2.0.0.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["browser.js", "jquery-2.0.0.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
}
```

extension.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {command: "add" }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.toString());
        });
    });
});
```

browser.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.command == "add") {
        doAdd("click");
    }
});

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(document.readyState == "complete") {
        doAdd("onreadystatechange");
    }
};

function doAdd(reason) {
    if(reason == "click") {
        if(document.getElementById("add") == null) {
            localStorage[location.href] = "ready";
            $("body")
              .append("<ul id='menu'><li><a id='add' href='#'>Add div</a></li></ul>");
        }
    } else if(reason == "onreadystatechange") {
        if(localStorage[location.href] == "ready") {
            if(document.getElementById("add") == null) {
                $("body")
                  .append(
                     "<ul id='menu'><li><a id='add' href='#'>Add div</a></li></ul>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```